# Quick search by related entity field - CRM 2011

Tags: search, customization, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Is there possible to do quick search by related entity fields?
In example, if we have Contact lookup field on Lead entity. Can we search Leads by Contact's email address or address name?
Can you refer me to some tutorials.

I know that this is possible by using 'Advance find' option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible to natively configure quick search to set attributes on related entities as "find columns".

As you might be aware, the native solution would be to find contacts by email address then open their record to look at their Leads.

The only other solution I can imagine would be to embed a custom Silverlight or ASPX page behind a navigation or ribbon button. In this case you could execute your own logic for searching but would not get the rich functionality of the native CRM grid without a lot of work.

Comment: Another (admittedly inelegant) solution might be to create an SSRS report that takes the email address as a parameter. I'd only go this route if my technical skills made the SilverLight / ASPX approach too difficult though. It's not a nice option really.